# Comment about a video

Tags: video, music

can I ask you some comments about this video?

I'd like to do a video like that.. Can anybody tell me a good SW to do that?

Thank you

Comment: You have to be more specific in your question. For example you can ask what software is needed to do a certain effect in the video. Or what camera lenses you'll need. Now the question is way to broad. Besides that, SW is the least of your worries when you want to produce such a movie. Lights, cameras, actors and good production staff are very important.

Comment: What specifically are you interested in here? Which effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot of hard work by a lot of hard working professional people that obviously love what they are doing as witnessed by how easy they made it look.

First start with this really talented band that knows their material inside and out. Take a close look, do you see any other mics in the scene beside the one for the lead vocalist?

There's no mics on the amps, or any on the drums for that mater. You can't get that sound without mic'ing everything and their brother. This band had to do a heck of a job of making it look live when indeed they are miming a master recording--not once but for possibly many takes. These are both fine musicians and actors at work and that's what you get when you have talent in the hands of good a director.

Next you have a crew that is so good you don't even know they are there. Likely two or three live camera feeds otherwise you would have to have that band play it over and over again to get all those shots with a single camera. Speaking of cameras, likely some high end gear, maybe a Canon 5d mark II or III, or maybe even a Red or who knows but it is something that has some great glass on it. Camera(s) like this cost over 2K and as much as 40K and then add the cost of the glass.

Did you notice the lighting? Perhaps not, it's so natural you would think there isn't a light on anywhere albeit there are a couple of shots with that box light on the floor in the left corner. Then there's the post production color grading, this a pro job by someone that understands and has lots of experience in color grading never mind the software.

How about that make up? Wardrobe? The decor? Who did the location scouting and pre-production planning? Guitar and amp techs? Catering? Security?

There is so much more here that is significant to speak about than the editing suite. I don't mean to chide you or discourage you as this is truly an inspiring piece of work and begs the question: "how?"

Comment: Ok, it seems not an "easy work".. I had to work hard to get a result like that, with many people that helps me for lights and so on! Thank you very much for the "recap" of all the important things to learn.. Now I now how to approach this world!

Comment: I recommend that you watch more videos you like and see if you can contact the directors or others in the credits on more information. For instance, let's say you like the editing, you might address the editor and ask how he/she got a certain effect. Pro editing suites include Avid, Final Cut Pro, Adobe Premier/After Effects and Vegas Pro. Please note that some production companies will have their own proprietary software specifically written by their staff of expert programmers and editing designers.

Answer (score 1):

To do a video like that you can use any pro or semi-pro editing suite.

But they will not enable you to produce something like that unless you have some experience in directing and in composing.

There really is nothing deeply technical required to do this, so unfortunately you won't be able to just buy some software and assume you can do this.